# How does linux kernel create /dev/root - Initramfs query

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, bootloader, yocto

I need to create a initramfs to load a driver to access EMMC which contains rootfs.

- In my current kernel build EMMC driver is modular ( sorry, can't change this ).
- After the kernel boots, it loads initramfs.
- From initramfs, it needs to switch to a partition on the EMMC which contains actual rootfs using switch_root function.

Till here it is all works well. I can create initramfs, get the kernel to load it and then also get it to switch to /dev/mmcblk0p2 which is the EMMC partition containing the actual rootfs.
My query:

After the booting is complete, mount command shows the following:

rootfs on / type rootfs (rw)

**/dev/mmcblk0p2 on / type ext4 (rw,sync,noatime,data=ordered)**

proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)
<...>

/dev/mmcblk0p1 on /var/volatile/run/media/mmcblk0p1 type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,sh)

/dev/mmcblk0p3 on /var/volatile/run/media/mmcblk0p3 type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)

/dev/mmcblk0p4 on /var/volatile/run/media/mmcblk0p4 type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)

If I build the EMMC driver as a part of the kernel ( and get rid of initramfs ), the output is very different:

rootfs on / type rootfs (rw)

**/dev/root on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,discard,journal_checksum,commit=1,data=ordered)**

devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=112272k,nr_inodes=28068,mode=755)
<....>

/dev/mmcblk0p1 on /var/volatile/run/media/mmcblk0p1 type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,sh)

/dev/mmcblk0p3 on /var/volatile/run/media/mmcblk0p3 type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)

/dev/mmcblk0p4 on /var/volatile/run/media/mmcblk0p4 type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)

- Though when I checked kernel logs and major, minor device numbers I found that /dev/root corresponds to /dev/mmcblk0p2 only.
- But I can not figure out why the output of mount is different.

After having spent so much effort in getting initramfs to work, I don't want to miss out on anything trivial. Any help, greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you don't get the help you're looking for here, you may try also on the Linux & Unix Stack Exchange site: http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It looks like your filesystem on /dev/mmcblk0p2 is mounted in initramfs with "safe options" and not remounted with "performance options" while the system runs the scripts from rootfs.

Comment: Thanks Roland and SnakeDoc. I could get /dev/mmcblk0p2 to the following now: /dev/mmcblk0p2 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,discard,journal_checksum,commit=1,data=ordered). This is still not the same as the first case which is /dev/root on / type ext4. Can you provide more details to "performance options"

Comment: Your question is really not clear. What are you asking here?